# Bucket sort---why's the input range important?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm doing an algorithms course at uni, and I read the following sentence on Introduction to Algorithms 3ED, p200:

> ...bucket sort is fast because it assumes something about the input. Whereas counting sort assumes that the input consists of integers in a small range, bucket sort assumes that the input is generated by a random process that distributes elements uniformly and independently over the interval **[0,1)**

Why is it that the input has to be in [0,1)? Why can't any uniformly distributed sequence be sorted using bucket sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine that the interval [0, 1) is used in order to obtain a theoretical result. Notice, however that any interval can easily be converted to the given interval so there is no loss of generality. That is, in practice any uniformly distributed sequence can be sorted using bucket sort.

Answer (score 0):

The text given in your question only points out the conditions about the input for counting sort and bucket sort. For counting sort the assumption about the input is that the range of integers in the list for sorting is very small. Where as the statement about bucket sort make another assumption about the input values. Here the range can be arbitrarily large but the distribution of the numbers in this range should be uniform. The value [0,1) in the statement about bucket sort do not mean the range in which bucket sort is effective. It simply tells you the nature of the input values.